# Handle Null values in server side or client side?

Tags: android, node.js, json, server, moshi

I have a Json that contains a lot of null values.
Is it better that server eliminate null values and then send it to client
or server send all data to client then the null values handle in client side? 
which method has less overhead and increase speed?

Comment: depends on how you are parsing json and if bandwidth is a factor. provide code, how you parse json on your client.

Comment: @finki with moshi that is a libarary in android to parse json files

Comment: I know, I'm using it. Show your code you need help on

Comment: If null doesn't have any semantic difference for your use case than absent, then avoid sending it from the server and save your users bytes over the network!

Answer (score 1):

Server should avoid sending null values as much as they can. Because putting all conditions at client side makes the response slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think null checking is better to be done from Server side but also it's not that much work if you just added null checking before using the object and its contents...